# why when i try to filter the ifconfig results with grep ether to show only mac address a media show up?

Tags: macos, grep, mac-address, ifconfig

When i do this commande a strange media show up in the results :
this is the command : 
`ifconfig | grep "ether"`
and the results :
`ether 78:7b:8a:c4:ee:19 
    media: autoselect (1000baseT )
    ether 24:f6:77:00:87:ca 
    ether 22:00:40:b0:0c:00 
    ether 22:00:40:b0:0c:01 
    ether 22:00:40:b0:0c:00 
    ether 06:f6:77:00:87:ca 
    ether a2:a0:9a:da:66:a6`

Comment: I can't reproduce it here , but maybe, it comes from stderr ?
what about `ifconfig 2>/dev/null | grep "ether"` ?

Comment: the same thing media still there

Comment: not really answering your question, but , what about : `networksetup -getmacaddress en0` ?

Comment: @user801247 I work in a computer connected to my school server could that be the reason??

Comment: that doesn't mean much to me, what do you mean by connected ? what your school server has so special ?

Comment: i don't have a computer i work on a server with other students

Comment: ok, got it , still , I have no explanation ... are you sure you are using macos bundled grep ? is that /usr/bin/grep ?

Comment: this is my grep version : grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

Comment: Is this result consistent : does it happen every time you run the command ? the formatting of the first ether line is strange too (no spacing) so the grep could grab 2 lines

Comment: but they are 2 lines between the ether line and the media line